# Issue with displaying a combined list

Tags: php, arrays, list, foreach

I am facing an issue.... Please help me..

**I have 2 strings:**

```
$teamslist = BAL@DET,WAS@SF,LA@STL,LAA@KC;
$string = BAL,WAS,LA,LAA,DET,SF,STL,KC;
```

What i want to is to check $string is element is found in $teamslist, than its display the whole name in $teamslist...

e.g:

I have **"BAL"** in $string, i want to check weather its found in $teamlist... if its found, than result should be

```
$result will be = BAL@DET
```

Code that i am using is working for one condition but not for 2nd condition... IF BAL is found before @ sign, its display correct result.. but if its found after @ sign, it display sometime a letter or nothing.. please help me to solve my second issue... That if word is either before @ or after @ sign, it display correct result for both...

Hope this understand my problem.. the code i am trying is :

```
foreach($string as $tag)
{                               
        $teamslisto = substr($teamslist, strpos($teamslist, $tag)+strlen($tag));
        $teamslisto2 = substr($teamslist, strpos($teamslist, $tag) - strlen($tag) -1);
        $final=explode(",",$teamslisto);
        $final2=explode(",",$teamslisto2);

            if($final['0']=="")
            {
                $opkplay = $final2['0'];
            }
            else 
            {
                $opkplay = $tag.$final['0'];
            }
}
```

Please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You could also use `stripos()` in this case too:</strike>

Revision: That stripos could make false matches explode the teams, and in array instead.

```
$teamslist = 'BAL@DET,WAS@SF,LA@STL,LAA@KC';
$string = 'BAL,WAS,LA,LAA,DET,SF,STL,KC';

$teamslist = explode(',', $teamslist);
$string = explode(',', $string);

$result = array();
foreach($string as $tag) {
    foreach($teamslist as $teams) {
        $temp = explode('@', $teams);
        if(in_array($tag, $temp)) {
            $result[$tag] = $teams;
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Okay thats good, but its there anyway that it could be done with the same way i posted code above... cz i have already so much foreach loop so i dn't to include a  new one again....

Comment: @DeDevelopers no, the two loops in this answer is fine, since both `$teamslist` and `$string` must be exploded, and you need checking for each team list for also every exploded `$string`

Comment: Your code will find `LA` in `LAA@KC` - do not think it is correct

Comment: @DeDevelopers you could try this revision

Comment: Thanks buddy.. i used this way and providing me exactly what i want.. thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with `preg_match()`:

```
$teamslist = 'BAL@DET,WAS@SF,LA@STL,LAA@KC,FOO@BAR';
$string = 'BAL,WAS,LA,LAA,DET,SF,STL,KC';

$persons = explode(',', $string);
$result = array();

foreach($persons as $person) {
    if(preg_match('/' . $person . '@[^@,]+|[^@,]+@' . $person . '/', $teamslist, $match) === 0)
        continue;

    if(in_array($match[0], $result) === false)
        $result[] = $match[0];
}

var_dump($result);
```

This will result in:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'BAL@DET' (length=7)
  1 => string 'WAS@SF' (length=6)
  2 => string 'LA@STL' (length=6)
  3 => string 'LAA@KC' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$teamslist = "BAL@DET,WAS@SF,LA@STL,LAA@KC";
$string = "BAL,WAS,LA,LAA,DET,SF,STL,KC";


$strings = explode(',', $string);
$result = array();
foreach($strings as $str)
{ 
  $escaped = preg_quote($str); // just in case..
  if (preg_match_all('/(^|,)([^@]+@' . $escaped. '|' . $escaped . '@[^@]+)($|,)/iU',
                     $teamslist, $matches))
    $result[$str] = $matches[2];
}
var_dump($result);
```

Result

```
array(8) {
  ["BAL"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "BAL@DET"
  }
  ["WAS"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "WAS@SF"
  }
  ["LA"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "LA@STL"
  }
  ["LAA"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "LAA@KC"
  }
  ["DET"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "BAL@DET"
  }
  ["SF"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "WAS@SF"
  }
  ["STL"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "LA@STL"
  }
  ["KC"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "LAA@KC"
  }
}
```

Values are arrays just in case if there will be a few teams with the same parts.